# C++ CRITICAL_SECTION object in .dll gives unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dllexport

I'm currently developing a game that comes in two parts: the engine is in a .dll and the actual game code is part of an .exe. The engine, among other header files, contains one that manages all components, ranging from Win32 specific objects and pointers to D3D11. These components are included in a class that allows them to be accessed globally via a function that returns a reference to it. Furthermore, for every item it manages there are two functions that allow the component to be set or to be returned. I also added a thread protection using a critical section. 
So, in State.h I have:

```
#if defined(NF3D_NONCLIENT_BUILD)
        #define NF3D_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #if defined(__MINGW32__)
            #define NF3D_API NF3D_API
        #else
            #define NF3D_API __declspec(dllimport)
        #endif
    #endif
...
#endif

...

extern NF3D_API CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;

class NF3D_API NF3DLock
{
public:
#pragma prefast( suppress:26166, "Thread safeness is enabeled." )
    FORCEINLINE _Acquires_lock_(CriticalSection) NF3DLock(void)  { EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); }
#pragma prefast( suppress:26165, "Thread safeness is enabeled." )
    FORCEINLINE _Releases_lock_(CriticalSection) ~NF3DLock(void) { LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); }
};

class NF3D_API STATE
{
public:
    ...
    inline void SetMember(int val) { NF3DLock Lock; Elements.Member = val; }
    inline int GetMember(void) { NF3DLock Lock; return Elements.Member; }

private:
    struct ELEMENTS
    {
        int Member;
    } Elements;
}

FORCEINLINE NF3D_API STATE* NF3DGetEngineState(void);
```

In State.cpp I initialise and delete the critical section but also:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;

...

FORCEINLINE NF3D_API STATE* NF3DGetEngineState(void)
{
    static STATE s_State;
    return &s_State;
}
```

Calling 'NF3DGetEngineState' inside the .dll causes no problems and the compilation runs perfectly, but if I use this function outside the engine, inside the application I get a linker error in the .exe:

```
2>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION NewFrontiers3D::CriticalSection" (?CriticalSection@NewFrontiers3D@@3U_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION@@A)
```

The engine is included in a namespace called 'NewFrontiers3D'.
This error intrigued me even more when I declared 'extern NF3D_API CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection' as static, as it compiled fine but gave an access violation exception when entering the critical section in the constructor of NF3DLock. Also, if I remove 'EnterCriticalSection' and LeaveCriticalSection' the linker errors disappear. I don't know what is happening and why is it happening and that's why I'm addressing this question to anybody who might be able to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

From the line:

```
#define NF3D_API __declspec(dllexport)
```

it looks like you are always exporting, and never importing (which you should do when the header is included from external projects).

For example, compile your code using defining NM3D_API_EXPORTS macro (if I am not mistaken: -d option.

And, then, in the header define NM3D_API in the following way:

```
#ifdef NM3D_API_EXPORTS
#define NM3D_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NM3D_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

**Original Post:**

Include's work in a very dumb way. They take whole contents of the file you are including, and paste them over the include statement.

This is why, when you are trying to include this header to a different project, that project doesn't know about your declaration in previous .dll. Since it was done in a different file, about which your other project knows nothing about.

Comment: What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: @VictorGabrielUngureanu Well, if I know *why* your code is failing, doesn't mean I know the correct solution for your problem. But still, the first thought that comes to mind would be to avoid global variables (or definitions of them), in the public .dll header, but instead, write a wrapper function, that returns that variable (i.e. write GetCriticalSection () that returns the CriticalSection variable).

Comment: Also, as a side question, can you call any other function defined in your .dll externally? On the second look it seems that you are only exporting the code, but never importing (which you should do in the case when your header is included from external projects)

Comment: Indeed, I thought about that same thing and it works, but I just tried to avoid using additional functions and I was wondering if there would be a different way of solving this. Thank you for your much needed help.

Comment: Yes, I can call other functions. I have, in quite the same manner, a function that returns the reference to the logging system and it works fine.

Comment: Actually, I have: '#if defined(NF3D_NONCLIENT_BUILD)
   #define NF3D_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
   #if defined(__MINGW32__)
    #define NF3D_API NF3D_API
   #else
    #define NF3D_API __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
  #endif'

Comment: @VictorGabrielUngureanu No offense, but since your code didn't show that (it showed only exporting), I only pointed out at what looked erroneous in a current sample. If you omitted that part entirely, I would've assumed that it was defined correctly.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, it was my fault. Thank you again for your help! :)